# How to disable options in form based on current data in database in Django?

Tags: python, html, django

I have a form where users can enter a timestamp whenever they have messed up the time they submitted previously. I am changing it so that the timestamp submitted can be either an entry or an exit, based on the button the user clicks. Right now, I have two boxes for the user to enter their timestamp, to know whether is an entry or an exit timestamp, like shown below:

```
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label for="chk"><input type="checkbox" value="0" id="chk" /> Requires manager approval</label>
                </div>
                <div style="padding-top: 10px; text-align: center; display: none" id="appreq">
                    <input type="checkbox" value="0" id="modinchk" /> Modify Entry
                    <div style="display: none" id="modin">
                        <label>Time In</label>
                        {% standard_input form.modified_in datetimepicker=True hide_label=True %}
                    </div>

                    <input type="checkbox" value="0" id="modoutchk" /> Modify Exit
                    <div style="display: none" id="modout">
                        <label>Time Out</label>
                        {% standard_input form.modified_out datetimepicker=True hide_label=True %}
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Is there a way to change it so that there is some sort of temporary variable, so that I can have only one box where they enter the date/time and when they click either enter or exit, the temporary variable data moves to either modified_in or modified_out? I imagine this second part would be handled in views, but I don;t know how I can have a temporary variable instead of sending it directly to modified_in/out. Should I just create a temporary timestamp to handle in views?

Comment: This might not be the best/optimal solution but have you considered using ```<select>```? Because you can do it in a way such that you have two options ```Time In, Time Out``` and then the user can just pick which and press one **"Submit"** button.